# Chris Banes PullToRefreshListView with custom list items

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I'm working on an Android application, which has PullToRefreshListView. But I can't load the custom list items into that listview.

The listview data is loaded from a webservice call within an AsyncTask. But when i set adapter from the onPostExecute() it doesn't show any items even though the getView() of the adapter called.

The listview is in a fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myproject, container,
            false);
    context = getActivity();
    projectsPullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.projects_listview);
    projectsListView = projectsPullToRefreshView.getRefreshableView();
    projectsPullToRefreshView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    myProjects = new ArrayList<Project>();
    projectsAdapter = new ProjectsListAdapter(context,
            R.layout.activity_projects_listitem, myProjects, this);
    projectsPullToRefreshView.setAdapter(projectsAdapter);

    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    projectsPullToRefreshView
            .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh(
                        PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                    String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(
                            getActivity(),
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),
                            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME
                                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE
                                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

                    // Update the LastUpdatedLabel
                    refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy()
                            .setLastUpdatedLabel(label);

                    // Do work to refresh the list here.
                    loadAllProjects();
                }
            });

    // Add an end-of-list listener
    projectsPullToRefreshView
            .setOnLastItemVisibleListener(new OnLastItemVisibleListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLastItemVisible() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "End of List!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    loadAllProjects();
    projectsPullToRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);

    return view;
}
```

and the AsyncTask has a custom callback,

```
    @Override
public void onWebServiceCompleted(Object response, int requestCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GET_PROJECTS) {

            if (project.getProjects() != null) {
                myProjects.addAll(project.getProjects());
                projectsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                projectsPullToRefreshView.onRefreshComplete();
            }


    } 
}
```

When I use the same adapter in normal ListView, it works fine.

Comment: sorry, used Fragment, Should have used PullToRefreshListFragment, working fine now